# Spontaneous transfer (decay) between Zeeman states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, quantum-optics, spectroscopy

In a paramagnetic substance like Rubidium (due to its unpaired valence electron), under the influence of a DC magnetic field, the degenerate electronic energy states split into Zeeman states. Let's consider four such states, with #1 being the highest energy and #4 the lowest, for our previous degenerate excited state. If we use a tunable laser to excite an atom to its, let's say, Zeeman state #1, **could the atom undergo spontaneous decay to one of the lower Zeeman states, such as #4, before returning to the ground state?** I envisage a process akin to fluorescence emission, where the atom initially transitions non-radiatively and fast to the lower states within the excited state band-like structure, followed by radiative decay to the ground state.

I personally think such a process could indeed occur, especially considering that paramagnetic materials allow for paramagnetic electron resonance (EPR) spectroscopy. This implies that the coupling between Zeeman states could be nonzero, so that spontaneous decay rate could be non-zero. However, I'm not entirely certain. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me understand this concept further.